# get key-chains of a tree in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I wanted to get key-chains of a tree, from every root to every leave.

for example input tree:

```
{"b" {:term true}, "a" {"y" {:term true}, "x" {:term true}}}
```

I was expecting output:

```
(("b" :term) ("a" "x" :term) ("a" "y" :term)) or ["b" "ax" "ay"]
```

I've figured out a tail-recursion, it worked fine:

```
(defn down-strings [trie] 
  "this one works. 80msecs for address.txt, not bad at all"
  (lazy-seq 
    (loop [strings [],trie trie] 
      (if (empty? trie) strings
        (let [[k v] (first trie)] 
          (recur (if (:term v) (conj strings k) strings)
                 (reduce 
                   conj 
                   (rest trie)
                   (map (fn [[dk dv]] [(str k dk) dv]) (dissoc v :term)))))))))
```

Now I have trouble with my recursive practice:

```
(defn down-strings [trie]
  (if (map? trie)
      (map (fn [[k v]] (conj (down-strings v) k)) trie)
      []))
```

the output is :

```
(("b" [:term]) ("a" ("y" [:term]) ("x" [:term])))
```

I tried everything I could, couldn't fix this.

Comment: `#(let [[dk dv] %] [(clojure.string/join [k dk]) dv])` is better written as the identical `(fn [[dk dv]] [(str k dv) dv])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn down-strings [trie]
  (mapcat
    (fn [[k v]]
      (if (map? v) (map (partial str k) (down-strings v)) [""]))
    trie))
```

For example,

```
(down-strings {"b" {:term true}, "a" {"y" {:term true}, "x" {:term true}}})
;("ax" "ay" "b")
```

I expect this to be quite a bit slower than [@noisesmith's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25270134/1562315).

Comment: thank you @Thumbnail again! Laterly I find everytime 'map' gives me a mess, 'mapcat' comes as a rescue. I should pay more attention of Clojure's seq.

Comment: @Choulin Do look at the solutions to [the question of which this *is* a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768802/how-can-i-get-the-nested-keys-of-a-map-in-clojure). There is much skill on display.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn down-strings
  ([trie] (down-strings trie []))
  ([trie prefix]
     (if (map? trie)
       (mapcat (fn [[k v]]
                 (down-strings v (conj prefix k)))
               trie)
       [prefix])))
```

A recursive solution is easier with an extra argument representing the accumulated state of each branch taken, and the usage of `mapcat` ensures that each path is one sequence, instead of deep nesting of sequences (an extra level of nesting per term in the path).
`

Comment: Thanks noisesmith. Finally start to know a bit how to think recursively.  If you want a flatten list as your final result, the internal result at the end of each iteration should be a flatten list at least!  That's how I failed with 'map'.