# changing nested map value without knowing keys

Tags: clojure

I need to change a value in a nested map where I don't know the values of keys in advance.  I have come up with the following to do that.

```
;; input  {String {String [String]}}
;; output {String {String String}}

(defn join-z
  [x-to-y-to-z]
  (zipmap (keys x-to-y-to-z)
          (map (fn [y-to-z] (into {} (map (fn [[y z]] {y (clojure.string/join z)})
                                          (seq y-to-z))))
               (seq (vals x-to-y-to-z)))))

(def example
  {"a" {"b" ["c" "d" "e"]}
   "m" {"n" ["o" "p"]}})

;; (join-z example) => {"m" {"n" "op"}, "a" {"b" "cde"}}
```

This seems to be a hack.  What is idiomatic clojure to do this?  Or, is there something like Haskell's lens library to use?

UPDATE:  based on `user5187212` answer

```
(defn update-vals [f m0]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] (assoc m k (f v)))
             {}
             m0))

;; (update-vals clojure.string/join {"b" ["c" "d" "e"]}) => {"b" "cde"}

(defn join-z [x-to-y-to-z]
  (update-vals (partial update-vals clojure.string/join) x-to-y-to-z))

;; (join-z example) => {"m" {"n" "op"}, "a" {"b" "cde"}}
```

This seems much more elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `reduce-kv`.

For the last layer you can use something like:

```
(defn foo [x]
  (reduce-kv
    (fn [m k v]
      (assoc m k (clojure.string/join v)))
    {}
    x))
```

then call it as many times as you need...

```
(reduce-kv 
   (fn [m k v]
     (assoc m k (foo v)))
   {} 
   example)
```

An other approach could be over [all nested keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768802/how-can-i-get-the-nested-keys-of-a-map-in-clojure) and then

```
(reduce 
  (fn [m ks]
    (update-in m ks clojure.string/join))
  example
  all-nested-keys)
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, that is how you do it :)

I would go for something more like this:

```
(into {} (for [[k v] example]
           [k (into {} (for [[k2 v2] v]
                         [k2 (string/join v2)]))]))
```

Which is pretty much the same thing.

There is a library called Specter
https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter
for queries and transformations:

```
(ns specter.core
  (:require
   [clojure.string :as string]
   [com.rpl.specter :as s]))

(def example
  {"a" {"b" ["c" "d" "e"]}
   "m" {"n" ["o" "p"]}})

(s/transform
 [s/ALL s/LAST s/ALL s/LAST]
 string/join
 example)
```

Which I think is a pretty neat way to express it.